# R - Calculating mean of values in data frame column cycling through pre-determined intervals

Tags: r, dataframe, average, moving-average

Starting from a two-column data frame like the following:

```
value - distance (km)
10  1.2
9.5 1.7
10  4
9.5 6.5
10  7
10  7
10  7.6
8.5 11.6
9.5 11.7
8.5 14.8
9   15.2
9   15.3
8.5 17.4
8   17.8
7   21.2
4   24.6

[...]
```

I have to calculate several averages of the left column values while the values of the right column are between predetermined ranges of 10 km:
an average of the values between 0 and 10 km, an average of the values between 5 and 15 km, 10 and 20 km and so on.
Something like a moving average within predefined intervals with a partial overlap.
The output should be something like the following:

```
9.86 (the average of 0 km <= values < 10 km)
9.43 (... 5 km <= values < 15 km)
8.71 (... 10 km <= values < 20 km)
[...]
avgX (... 40 km <= values < 50 km)
```

I'm looking at the documentation of the different R moving average implementations but (because of me for sure) I'm not sure of the best/right way to achieve my goal.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your data (`dput(data)`) and an expected output so we can know what exactly you're looking for?

Comment: No idea what you want the averages over dataframe without data or expected output...can you provide more details?

Comment: thanks, I hope to made it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution, and you can try the code below:

```
res <- sapply(seq(0,max(df$distance),by=5),function(k) mean(subset(df, distance >= k & distance < k+10)$value))
```

such that

```
> res
[1] 9.857143 9.428571 8.714286 7.583333 5.500000
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(value = c(10, 9.5, 10, 9.5, 10, 10, 10, 8.5, 9.5, 
8.5, 9, 9, 8.5, 8, 7, 4), distance = c(1.2, 1.7, 4, 6.5, 7, 7, 
7.6, 11.6, 11.7, 14.8, 15.2, 15.3, 17.4, 17.8, 21.2, 24.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```